# MakePRI : warning +Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm building a TypeScript + Cordova project.  The project is using SystemJS, JSPM and Angular2.  When I debug the files on Windows Phone (Universal) I get the following warning

`1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: JEPSO-CI [D:\erase\BlankCordovaApp4\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'es-shims' but no resources found for default language(s):`

What is the purpose of the MakePRI warning?  Can this affect how the Windows App performs?

[image]